# QtVirtualkeyboard Languages issue on ARM processor

Tags: qt5

i am using Qt5.7.1 on debian jessie linux virtual machine and deploy my application on the iMx6 processor, also running Qt5.7.1 and debian jessie.

I compiled the QtVirtualkeyboard project to add all languages that Qt supports.
First i compiled it for the PC linux and after for the iMx6.
I copied the new build plugin into the iMx6 Qt install plugin path and the other files [required](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtvirtualkeyboard-deployment-guide.html).

So on PC side the "basic" example project shows all languages with no issue.
Running the same example project on iMx6, i get almost all languages except those:

qml: Qt.createQmlObject(): failed to create object: 
qrc:/QtQuick/VirtualKeyboard/content/layouts/ja_JP/japaneseInputMethod:1:57: JapaneseInputMethod is not a type

qml: Qt.createQmlObject(): failed to create object: 
qrc:/QtQuick/VirtualKeyboard/content/layouts/ko_KR/hangulInputMethod:1:57: HangulInputMethod is not a type

qml: Qt.createQmlObject(): failed to create object: 
qrc:/QtQuick/VirtualKeyboard/content/layouts/zh_CN/pinyinInputMethod:1:57: PinyinInputMethod is not a type

qml: Qt.createQmlObject(): failed to create object: 
qrc:/QtQuick/VirtualKeyboard/content/layouts/zh_TW/tcInputMethod:1:57: TCInputMethod is not a type

Did i miss to copy a source file for those languages or something?
If yes which files and where should they be copied to?

Comment: Have you ever solved this?

Answer (score 0):

So i did made it to work.The problem is that QtVirtualkeyboard  uses thirdparty libraries and it cannot find it. 
To solve the proble you must also compile all QtVirtualkeyboard thirdparty libraries and copy it to your ARM CPU like iMx6.

Example for simple chinese:

cd /home/yourname/Qt5.9.1/5.9.1/Src/qtvirtualkeyboard/src/virtualkeyboard/3rdparty/pinyin

qmake

make

Copy the .dat library for pinyin (dict_pinyin.dat) to directory like
/usr/local/qt5.9.1/qtvirtualkeyboard/pinyin

Now QtVirtualkeyboard should find the simple chinese dictonary. This should be done for japonese and traditional chinese and hundspell as well if you use them.